# Deployment Groups deploying to different server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I'm very new to Azure Devops. Successfully created CI/CD pipeline for Sql database using dacpac. SQL servers are sitting on AZ VM.
As part of it I have created a deployment group and ran power shell script generated by azure on **server A**.
While creating CD pipeline, mistakenly given **Server B** as target server for deployment.
Surprising it was not failed, deployment was successful.

I thought each server should be added to the deployment group. but with out adding the server B I'm able to deploy. Can somebody explain the behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment to Server B was successful is because Server B is accessible from Server A (You can have a test using [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-ps&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15) to connect to server B from server A).

When you created a deployment group on server A, you also installed a pipeline agent on the server. When you run the deployment group job in CD pipeline. it would be executed on the pipeline agent on the server A. And since Server B is accessible from Server A, So the deployment will be successful.

For better understanding the situation. Let's say you create a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on your Azure VM. You can deploy to the sql server hosted on the same Azure VM. And any other sql servers on different machines as long as they can be accessed from the machine where the self-hosted agent is installed.

Comment: so deployment group is kind of agent pool ? if so am I able to use this for ci pipeline as wel?

Comment: @vignesh You cannot use deployment group for ci pipeline. it is only for release pipeline.